# How Do I change the color of webgl points?

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, webgl

This is the code I used to try to change the color of WebGL points:

I want to change the color of WebGL points when a user clicks the body element.
And FYI the shaders are compiling correctly.

The numbers in the color_obj object seem to be changing when I click on the screen. However, the WebGL colors don't change. Can someone help me with this?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

gl.clearColor(0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT || gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

if (!gl) {
    throw new Error("WebGL not supported");
}

console.log("This is working");

const points = [
    1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, 0.0
];

let color_obj = {
    color_1: 0.4,
    color_2: 0.7,
    color_3: 0.8,
    color_4: 0.0,
    color_5: 0.5,
}

let colors = [
    color_obj.color_1, color_obj.color_2, color_obj.color_3,
    color_obj.color_3, color_obj.color_1, color_obj.color_3,
    color_obj.color_4, color_obj.color_4, color_obj.color_4,
    color_obj.color_1, color_obj.color_2, color_obj.color_3,
    color_obj.color_4, color_obj.color_4, color_obj.color_4,
    color_obj.color_5, color_obj.color_5, color_obj.color_5
];

const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const buffer_2 = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer_2);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW)

const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, `
precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 pos;
attribute vec3 rgb;
varying vec3 rgbColor;

void main() {
    rgbColor = rgb;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1);
}
`);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, `
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 rgbColor;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(rgbColor, 1);
}
`);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

const program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);

const positionRef = gl.getAttribLocation(program, `pos`);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionRef);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionRef, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

const colorRef = gl.getAttribLocation(program, `rgb`);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorRef);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer_2);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorRef, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.useProgram(program);

document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    console.log("Body Clicked");
    color_obj.color_1 += 0.1;
    color_obj.color_2 += 0.1;
    color_obj.color_3 += 0.1;
    color_obj.color_4 += 0.1;
    color_obj.color_5 += 0.1;

    console.log(color_obj.color_1);
    console.log(color_obj.color_2);
    console.log(color_obj.color_3);
    console.log(color_obj.color_4);
    console.log(color_obj.color_5);
});

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>WebGL</title>
    <style>
        canvas {
            position:fixed;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }

        html, body {
            margin:0 !important;
            padding:0 !important;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in `color_obj` are merely copied into the `colors` array that you use to write them to the buffer(`buffer_2`), so while your click handler updates the `color_obj` it doesn't update the `colors` array let alone the actual buffer that's used by webgl. You need to bind the buffer and set its data in your click handler for changes to take any effect.